# How to get the information of the last packet recieved using Scapy

Tags: python, packet, scapy, packets

I am using `srp1()` of Scapy to replay pcap file to a device as follows:

```
for p in rdpcap(pcapfile):
    ...
    rcv = srp1(p, 'eth0')
    print rcv[IP].len
    print rcv[TCP].seq
    ...
```

When the device sends 1 packet I can get its `IP.len` and `TCP.seq`, but when it sends 2 packets, I can get only the information of the first packet while I need the information of the second one.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Both [*Scapy*'s user manual](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html) and [*Scapy*'s API documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf) state that `srp1()` is a variant of `srp()` that returns just the first packet that constitutes an answer for the sent packet/s.

Therefore, try using `srp()` instead of `srp1()`, as follows:

```
for p in rdpcap(pcapfile):
    ...
    answers, unanswered = srp(p, 'eth0')
    last_request, last_answer = answers[-1]
    print last_answer[IP].len
    print last_answer[TCP].seq
    ...
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but got this error
"AttributeError: 'list' Object has no attribute 'seq'"

I printed the received packet, it looks like this:

"[<Ether dst=....| <IP version=... | <TCP .. seq=**.. | <Raw load=....|>>>>]"

Comment: Are you sure you've extracted the last answer received, i.e. `rcv = srp(p, 'eth0')[-1]` rather than `rcv = srp(p, 'eth0')`?

Comment: What is the value of `rcv` just before the error is raised?

Comment: rcv = srp(p, 'eth0')[-1]       print rcv       this is the result:     [<Ether dst=....| <IP version=... | <TCP .. seq=**.. | <Raw load=....|>>>>]


"..." means other attributes

Comment: last_answer = answers[-1] with some packets return "IndexError: list index out of range" and last_answer[IP].len return "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not Packet_metaclass"